# Question regarding open subsets in metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am having trouble conceptualizing the following theorem:

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a metric space $X$. Then a subset $U$ of $Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $U=V \cap Y$ for some open subset $V$ of $X$.

Consider the following scenario.
$X$ is the set of real numbers.
$V$ is the open set of reals $ \lbrace 0<x<1 \rbrace $.
$Y$ is the closed set of reals $ \lbrace 0.25 \leq x \leq 0.75 \rbrace $
If we define $V \cap Y = U$, clearly $U=Y$ which is closed, which would apparently contradict the theorem.

What am I missing here?

Comment: $Y$ is both open and closed in $Y$. I don't see any issue here.

Comment: $Y$ is closed as a subset of $X$, but $Y$ is open (and closed) as a subset of $Y$. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is both open and closed. But $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not open.

Comment: The most important piece of the theorem is "**is open in $Y$**". And indeed, $U=Y$ is always open in $Y$ regardless of what $Y$ is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open or closed subset respect to the Subset Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848937/open-or-closed-subset-respect-to-the-subset-topology)

Answer (score 0):

Here the set $Y$ is trivially open in $Y$ as long as $Y$ is a topological space. Whether the set $ Y $ satisfies any topological property in the ambient space $ X $ is irrelevant here.